# Is it possible to assign several functions to one URL in Django?

Tags: python, django

Say I have these functions in my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def foo(request):
    a = 2
    return render_to_response('test.html', {'a': a})

def bar(request):
    b = 3
    return render_to_response('test.html', {'b': b})
```

This would be my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

(r'^test/$', views.foo, views.bar),

)
```

Obviously this is not my real code, but would it be possible to assign several view functions to one URL? If so, what am I doing wrong? I'm sort of new to Django so don't use really complicated Django jargon.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

The idea behind your urls file is that you're telling the framework what function to call for a given url. If you give it more than one function, how will it know where to send the request?

If you want to separate out the functionality into a few different functions, the simplest solution is to create a dispatching view, something like the following:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^test/$', 'myapp.views.dispatch'),
)
```

views.py:

```
def dispatch(request):
    if something:
        return foo(request)
    else:
        return bar(request)
```